# Best solution to functional permissions on django multi-site app

Tags: django, django-permissions

I have two sites running off the same base code.  Each site has different requirements for which functions different user types can see.  For example, one site says anyone can view the News page but on the other only logged in users with a value in the user profile of 'Manager" can see the news.

So the first level of managing these permissions is easy, each site has a different set of templates and in the menu template I show or don't show the menu item depending on the user profile.  But how do I prevent a user just typing in the url for the news page?

- I can't remove news from the urls.py
  because I don't have a request value
  at the point
- I could write a custom
  decorator for the view that accesses
  a model or a settings value to
  determine if the current user has
  access
- I could do something in
  middleware?
- Or there might be a
  better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So went with the custom decorator in the end that queries a value in SETTINGS.